# How can I make figwheel start with a custom initial namespace?

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

The project.clj of my clojurescript code specifies `:repl-options {:init-ns my-project.core}` and I start figwheel via `start-figwheel!`. In the figwheel [documentation](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#scripting-figwheel) it says that

```
;; you can also just call (ra/start-figwheel!)
;; and figwheel will do its best to get your config from the
;; project.clj or a figwheel.edn file`
```

But when figwheel starts, it puts me into the `cljs.user` namespace. How can I make figwheel pick up this option?

My figwheel.clj looks as follows:

```
(require '[figwheel-sidecar.repl :as r]
         '[figwheel-sidecar.repl-api :as ra])

(ra/start-figwheel!
  {:figwheel-options {}
   :build-ids ["dev"]
   :all-builds
   [{:id "dev"
     :figwheel {:devcards true}
     :source-paths ["src"]
     :compiler {:main 'my-project.core
                :asset-path "js"
                :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                :output-dir "resources/public/js"
                :verbose true}}]})

(ra/cljs-repl)
```

I am basically asking [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-tools/LewrRfhepw8) from Google groups.

Comment: Is the namespace not changed when you connect from the external REPL client using `lein repl -c` or in the same REPL where you execute `(ra/start-figwheel)`?

Comment: I added my figwheel.clj. I'm connecting with my browser, and then the repl prompt shows up (with `cljs.user`) in the terminal where I launched the script. I tried `lein repl :connect 3449`, but this just hung.

Comment: I think `:repl-options` are used only by lein's repl task, not by figwheel itself. How do you use your `figwheel.clj`? Execute it as a script or load it in a REPL session?

Comment: I execute figwheel.clj on the command line via a bash script that contains the line `rlwrap lein run -m clojure.main script/figwheel.clj`. You're right, it's quite possible that `:repl-options` simply isn't picked up. A lot of the time I feel that I'm not fully aware of the tooling, which process calls what other process. I think I need to go draw some diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start-figwheel!` only starts figwheel logic. Regarding your finding that:

```
;; you can also just call (ra/start-figwheel!)
;; and figwheel will do its best to get your config from the
;; project.clj or a figwheel.edn file`
```

It indeed finds its config but [it's only `:figwheel` submap of `project.clj`](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/blob/a364ac2eb77a98bbd15bd483267c4f3f97cb5767/sidecar/src/figwheel_sidecar/config.clj#L276).

`:repl-options` are used by REPL when it starts. It seems that `figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/cljs-repl` doesn't allow specifying REPL options and it doesn't read them from `project.clj`.

You might try to play with starting `lein repl` where project.clj's `:repl-options` use `:init` option to provide the code you want to execute instead of a standalone script.

Comment: Thanks Piotrek for digging up the relevant figwheel code! So to summarize, instead of starting the repl from figwheel's repl API, I use lein's repl functionality, and load the figwheel code into it (via project.clj's `:init` option).

Comment: I put the call to `start-figwheel!` (and the `require` code) into a `do` thunk under `:init` and it didn't work because it can't find the source files. I also get the feeling that `:init` wasn't meant for this. So your answer is correct in that figwheel doesn't have a facility for picking up `:repl-options` from project.clj, but there doesn't seem to be much we can do about it.